# How to fix this error Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

**Error :**

```
[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'DatabaseSnapshot<any>' has no compatible call signatures.
(parameter) item: AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot<any>>
```

**File Consuming service**:

```
**Error is at ...Item.payLoad().val()**
 constructor(private service: EmployeeService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getEmployees().subscribe(list => {
      let array = list.map(item => {
        return { $key: item.key, **...item.payload().val()** }
      })
    });
  }
**Method-II**
    getEmployees() {
        this.employeeList = this.db.list('employees');
        return this.employeeList.snapshotChanges();
      }
```

Comment: Please, post the code, not images of it. It's really hard to help you like this.

Comment: I've changed it and pasted the actual code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item.payload` is a property and not a function, as you should see if you jump to [its definition](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/3152fc47bbb2560e003f411bff2d573bbae00f8d/src/database/interfaces.ts#L40) in your IDE:

```
export interface Action<T> {
  type: ListenEvent;
  payload: T;  // <---
};

export interface AngularFireAction<T> extends Action<T> {
  prevKey: string | null | undefined;
  key: string | null;
}
```

So you should use `item.payload` without calling it: remove the parentheses after `item.payload`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I've fixed the error and now it is working